# crystal reports extracting a single field from data source

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I am using SAP Crystal Reports 2016 Support Pack 4. This sounds really simple but I am finding it to be a bit challenging.

There is a report that I created that iterates of several columns.  What I am looking for is a way to extract one particular field from the table of data and display it in the report

For example, I want extract the 400 which is Column2,val4 data field and place it in the report.
Column 1     Column2
val1          100
val2          200
val3          300
val4          400
val5          500

How does one do this?

Comment: How do you get the data? Why don't you filter it?

Comment: The data is coming in via a view.  All the data in the table will be displayed in the report but I have a few fields I need to isolate and put in separate fields on the side.